# Python: _dop.error: failed in processing argument list for call-back fcn

Tags: python, ode

After having cleared my last error, I ran into another error and this error is more fundamental to the ode solver. Below is my error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cont_inside_f.py", line 36, in <module>
    x,t,u=solver(0,1e-2,10,[0,0],[a,eta,k,lam])
  File "cont_inside_f.py", line 24, in solver
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 408, in integrate
    self.f_params, self.jac_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 1032, in run
    tuple(self.call_args) + (f_params,)))
_dop.error: failed in processing argument list for call-back fcn.
```

I created a function that returns a list of lists. I wish to pass first element of this list to the ode solver for integration and second element of this returned list is something that I wish to plot later down my code. Kindly help me solve this error, thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode
from numpy import tanh,array,sin,cos

def f(t,Y,param):
    x1,x2=Y[0],Y[1]
    a,eta,k,lam=param[0],param[1],param[2],param[3]
    e=x1-2
    de=-2*x1+a*x2+sin(x1)
    s=de+lam*e
    u=(1/(a*cos(2*x1)))*(-eta*tanh(s)-k*s-(-2*x1+a*x2+sin(x1))*cos(x1)+2*(-2*x1+a*x2+sin(x1))+a*x2*cos(x1))
    x1dot=-2*x1+a*x2+sin(x1)
    x2dot=-x2*cos(x1)+cos(2*x1)*u
    x=[x1dot,x2dot]
    return [x,u]

def solver(t0,dt,t1,y0,param):
    x,u=[[] for i in range(2)],[]
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    r=ode(f(t0,y0,param)[0]).set_integrator('dopri5',method='bdf')
    r.set_initial_value(y0,t0).set_f_params(param)
    while r.successful() and r.t<t1:
        r.integrate(r.t+dt)
        for i in range(2):
            x[i].append(r.y[i])
        t.append(r.t)
        #u.append(f(r.t,[r.y[0],r.y[1]],param)[1])
        u.append(f(t0,y0,param)[1])

        #print(t)
    return x,t,u

if __name__=='__main__':
    a,eta,k,lam=2,1.2,3,2
    x,t,u=solver(0,1e-2,10,[0,0],[a,eta,k,lam])
    for i in range(3):
        if i!=2:
            plt.subplot(3,1,i+1)
            plt.plot(t,x[i])
        else:
            plt.subplot(3,1,i+1)
            plt.plot(t,u)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
r=ode(f(t0,y0,param)[0]).set_integrator('dopri5',method='bdf')
```

you do not pass a function pointer but the value at the point `t0,y0`. You could use a lambda expression to correct this,

```
 r=ode(lambda t,y: f(t,y,param)[0]).set_integrator('dopri5',method='bdf')
```

As the parameter passing is done here directly, you can not do it twice via the indirect `set_parameter_f`, as that messes up the argument stack. Just remove that part.

You also need to initialize the list for the `t` values, and the current value of `u` is obtained via

```
     u.append(f(r.t,r.y,param)[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lutz, I am getting the desired result provided I remove set_f_params() from my code. Can you explain why is that so? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The lambda expression only takes 2 arguments. With `set_f_params` the ODE solver tries to call it with 3 arguments in the stack `t,y,params`. The actually passed arguments get apparently taken from the top of the stack so that the lambda expression gets called with `t,y = y,params`. Then the lambda call adds `params` again so that `f` gets called with `t,y,params = y,params,params`, left the expected arguments, right the passed arguments. You can verify that if you add `print t,Y,params` as first line in `f`.

Comment: What if I do, lambda t,y,param: f(t,y,param)? Then will it work?

Comment: Yes, that links the interfaces correctly. But one would have to question the sanity of this double redirection. There may be situations where it makes sense, but I can not imagine ones based on the current code.